# Why do sprites in SpriteKit not bounce off the wall

Tags: ios, swift

I have a ball and bounding edges on the screen. I'm just testing the physics right now, and I want the ball to continuously bounce around the screen without slowing down.

```
let b = self.ball?.copy() as! SKShapeNode?

if b != nil {
    ball!.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat.random(min: -(self.frame.size.width/2), max: self.frame.size.width/2), y: CGFloat.random(min: -(self.frame.size.height/2), max: (self.frame.size.height/2)))

    b?.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
    b?.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
    b?.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0
    b?.physicsBody?.friction = 0

    self.addChild(b!)

    b?.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 1000, dy: 50))
}
```

The boundaries function properly, but the ball will bounce around the screen for a short time, and then will butt up against the edge and lose its y momentum and just move in the x direction back and forth.

I tried changing the last line to

```
b?.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 1000, dy: 50)
```

but it does the same thing. The restitution is also set to 1 on the boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

Set the friction of the wall to 0

```
wall.physicsBody?.friction = 0
```

Also set the gravity to zero

```
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: 0.0)
```

Comment: I did both of these, but it didn't effect the result.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are applying an impulse. You kind of noticed it but instead of writing

```
b?.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 1000, dy: 50)
```

you need to apply a vector so you need

```
b?.physicsBody?.applyForce(CGVector(dx: 1000, dy: 50))
```